# Using Replacement Rule on Part of List?

Tags: evaluation, replacement, warning-messages

Why can't I use a replacement rule to replace a variable name standing in for the index of a list?

For example:

```
myList={1,2,3,4,5}

myList[[index]]/.index->3
```

Mathematica does not like this and gives a message: "The expression index cannot be used as a part specification."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `ReplaceAll` does not hold its arguments, MMA tries to evaluate `myList[[index]]` and then replace any `index` it finds in the result. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer  Figured it was something with Hold.  It would be convenient to do this for some code where I have a lengthy expression with a lot of indices I'd like to change but don't want to localize the index or assign it globally.  Why doesn't ReleaseHold[Hold[ myList[[index]]/.index->3]] work?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer has given you the reason. Rather than trying to come up with jumping-through-hoops machinations to do it with a replacement, why not use, e.g. `With[{index = 3}, myList[[index]]]` - just enclose your "lengthy expression" in the `With`...

Comment: @ciao  Thanks. I can certainly use With[] but I'm surprised there isn't a simple tweak to the replacement rules that allows this to work.

Comment: @user13999, same reason as above, you are `Hold`ing the replacement as well, so it doesn't happen until `ReleaseHold`. This: `ReleaseHold[Hold[myList[[index]]] /. index -> 3]` OTOH works, but seems much more round-about than ciao's `With`-example (I would have used `With` as well) and I can't see any reason why replacement would be favourable here.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer  Ok, thanks for the explanation.  I agree, using With is simpler.

Comment: @ciao to not confuse OP let's add that in this case `With` is not special. `Module` or `Block` will do too.

Comment: `(myList[[index]] // Unevaluated) /. index -> 3` but I believe it was asked before.

Comment: @Kuba - agree, hence my use of "..., e.g..."